# Java combine explicit locks with synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking

I have a thread safe class Container:

```
public class Container {
  private int x;
  ...
  public synchronized int getX();
  public synchronized void setX(int x);
}
```

Then I have a list of containers:

```
List<Container> containers;
```

I would like to iterate through the list, aquire the container's lock at each iteration and, only at the end of loop, release all locks.
Something like this:

```
for(Container c : containers) {
  c.lock();
  //do stuff
}
for(Container c : containers)
  c.unlock();
```

**I still want other threads to be able to continue to use getX and setX methods of unlocked containers, but for various reasons I do not want to allow that for already analysed containers.**

**Do you know the java code for that?**

Better ideas are also appreciated.

Comment: How about having `lock()` and `unlock()` first and last in `getX` and `setX`?

Comment: @see [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Comment: @aioobe: I would like to combine synchronized methods with explicit locks (hoping that it is possibile, but I think it is because behind the scenes the synchronized keyword acquires the object lock).

Comment: @Lance Java: But in my case how would you use try-finally inside the for loop? Maybe try around all the for loop and finally releasing all the locks? Is ok to unlock a unlocked lock?

Comment: Regarding different approaches: if you explain what you do with Container maybe a solution with immutable Containers would be better...

Comment: @Kami, ok, I see your concern now. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible I'm afraid. The Java Language imposes a strict nesting principle with the `synchronized (...) { ... }` blocks (and synchronized methods).

That being said, there are nasty workarounds. In *bytecode* a synchronized block translates to two separate `monitorenter` / `monitorexit` instructions. The same thing can be achieved with `sun.mis.Unsafe.monitorEnter()` and `monitorExit()`.

In this case however, I would strongly encourage you to rethink the design. I would suggest you let `getX` and `setX` acquire / release an internal [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) (which the traversal method also uses). In particular, you could use [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) for your `setX` and `getX` methods. In fact, this approach is better than having `synchronized` methods for other reasons too. See for instance:

[Why is it a good practice to have separate locks instead of having lock on object that get modified in the synchronized block in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677501/why-is-it-a-good-practice-to-have-separate-locks-instead-of-having-lock-on-objec)

Comment: Does not the synchronized keyword acquire the lock of the object itself? It is like writing synchronized(this){} inside the method. If we are locking on this, why can not we create a lock that lock the object (this)?

Comment: With an internal lock, would not I have the same problem? How can  I acquire multiple internal locks (one at each iteration) without using the synchronized keyword?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The only reason we can't just do something like `lock(this);` and then later `unlock(this);` (which would correspond to the opening brace `{` resp. closing brace `}`of `synchronized (this)`) is that the only way to acquire this type of lock is through the synchronized keyword (unless you resort to unsafe operations as I've mentioned in my answer) and the synchronized keyword has the syntactical constraint of a `{ ... }` block.

Comment: No, with an internal lock, you could use `Lock` which has separate `lock()` and `unlock()` methods! (Answer updated.)

Comment: Thank you, but how can I write a try-finally block inside the for loop? I mean finally should I unlock all locks?

Comment: The same way as you posted in your question. Or do you want to use `try` / `finally` as in the keywords?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80368/discussion-between-kami-and-aioobe).

Comment: You mention `Unsafe.monitorEnter/Exit` - those also have poorer performance characteristics - benchmarked it in the past.
For best possible performance, you can modify the bytecode and use the MONITORENTER/EXIT instructions - just make sure it's impossible to have mismatched enters/exits. I don't recommend doing this unless forced into it by poor API design in code you don't control...

Comment: ... and even in that case there are probably acceptable workarounds which aren't as nasty.